# Querying on Global Secondary indexes with a usage of contains operator

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I've been reading a DynamoDB docs and was unable to understand if it does make sense to query on Global Secondary Index with a usage of 'contains' operator.

My problem is as follows: my dynamoDB document has a list of embedded objects, every object has a 'code' field which is unique:

```
    {

     "entities":[
            {"code":"entity1Code", "name":"entity1Name"}, 
            {"code":"entity2Code", "name":"entity2Name"}
       ]

   }
```

I want to be able to get all documents that contain entities with `entity.code = X`.
For this purpose I'm considering adding a Global Secondary Index that would contain all `entity.codes` that are present in current db document separated by a comma. So the example above would look like:

```
    {

     "entities":[
            {"code":"entity1Code", "name":"entity1Name"}, 
            {"code":"entity2Code", "name":"entity2Name"}
       ],
     "entitiesGlobalSecondaryIndex":"entityCode1,entityCode2"
   }
```

And then I would like to apply filter expression on `entitiesGlobalSecondaryIndex` something like: `entitiesGlobalSecondaryIndex contains entityCode1`.

Would this be efficient or using global secondary index does not make sense in this way and DynamoDB will simply check the condition against every document which is similar so scan?

Any help is very appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The contains operator of a query cannot be run on a partition Key. In order for a query to use any sort of operators (contains, begins with, > < ect...) you must have a range attributes- aka your Sort Key.

You can very well set up a GSI with some value as your PK and this code as your SK. However, GSIs *are* replication of the table - there is a slight potential for the data ina GSI to lag behind that of the master copy. If the query you're doing against this GSI isn't very often, then you're probably safe from that.

However. If you are trying to do this to the entire table at once then it's no better than a scan.

If what you need is a specific Code to return all its documents at once, then you could do a GSI with that as the PK. If you add a date field as the SK of this GSI it would even be time sorted. If you query against that code in that index, you'll get every single one of them.

Since you may have multiple codes, if they aren't too many per document, you maybe could use a Sparse Index - if you have an entity with code "AAAA" then you also have an attribute named AAAA (or AAAAflag or something.) It is always null/does not exist *Unless* the entities contains that code. If you do a GSI on this AAAflag attribute, it will only contain documents that contain that entity code, and ignore all where this attribute does not exist on a given document.  This may work for you if you can also provide a good PK on this to keep the numbers well partitioned and if you don't have too many codes.

Filter expressions by the way are different than all of the above. Filter expressions are run on tbe data that would be returned, after it is already read out of the table.  This is useful I'd you have a multi access pattern setup, but don't want a particular call to get all the documents associated with a particular PK - in the interests of keeping the data your code is working with concise.  The query with a filter expression still retrieves everything from that query, but only presents what makes it past the filter.

If are only querying against a particular PK at any given time and you want to know if it contains any entities of x, then a Filter expressions would work perfectly. Of course, this is only per PK and not for your entire table.

If all you need is numbers, then you could do a count attribute on the document, or a meta document on that partition that contains these values and could be queried directly.

Lastly, and I have no idea if this would work or not, if your entities attribute is a map type you might very well be able to filter against entities code - and maybe even with entities.code.contains(value) if it was an SK - but I do not know if this is possible or not